# d3 js how to retrieve time from a x position

Tags: d3.js, scale

I'm currently working on learning a little bit of the wonderfull d3.js library. Let's use a simple example for the purpose of my problem.

I have a date that I want to represent on a x Axis.

```
    var startDate = new Date();
    var x         = d3.time.scale().range([0, 1000]); //range of x axis will be 1000px

    var xPos      = x(startDate); // return the scaled date as a x position on x axis
```

Here's the problem : 
How do I get the original value from there ... in other words, how do I translate the x position as a date ? In other words again how do I get startDate from xPos ?

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 2):

Each scale has an `invert()` function that does what you want. See [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#wiki-invert).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just understand :) I was searching for the syntax so it's x.invert(xPos); and it return the startDate.